# Wish casting stress: How fast is recovery while resting?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

Part of the description of the *wish* spell:

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. ... In addition, your Strength drops to 3, if it isn't 3 or lower already, **for 2d4 days. For each of those days that you spend resting and doing nothing more than light activity, your remaining recovery time decreases by 2 days.** ...

If I take one day to rest, how many days the recovery time actually get reduced? Is it **3 days**, because one day has passed naturally and the description says it is reduced by (another) two days (A)? Or just follow the description and reduce it by **two days** at the end of the day (B)?

| end of day | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| no rest (remaining days) | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 (curse ends) |
| rest (remaining days) **A** | 7-2=5 | 4-2=2 | 1-2=-1 (end) |  |  |  |  |  |
| rest (remaining days) **B** | 7-2=5 | 5-2=3 | 3-2=1 | 1-2=-1 (end) |  |  |  |  |

**Is it 2 days in addition to or instead of 1 day of natural recovery?**

Answer (score 12):

### Double recovery speed while resting

Normally, each day you wait reduces the remaining necessary recovery time by one day. If you rest, the recovery time necessary decreases by two days **instead**.

This can be explained by the fact that a day has passed in either case, so replace a normal day with a more efficient recovery day. If another way of reducing the recovery time was listed that wasn't a variation on waiting a day we would have to assume that whatever reduction it would offer to recovery time was in addition to the normal reduction on the same day.

Comment: This can also be viewed as a case of "specific beats general": the general case is that each day counts as one day, and the more specific case allows certain days to count as 2 days instead.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Is it though? There is not really a rules contradiction to resolve with the rule. Reducing by one day and by two days could be true at the same time.

Comment: "For each of those days... your remaining recovery time decreases by 2 days" seems to explicitly support this interpretation. 'For each 1 day spent the time decreases by 2 days' is a direct relationship between those values. If it was intended to be an 'additional' 2 days on top of the 1 day spent, I'd expect the wording to say "... your remaining recovery time decreases by *an additional* 2 days".